# Windows : schedule a task with asian UPN for username

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, southeast-asian-languages

I'm publishing and shipping a small .NET application whose MSI installer requires the IT guy to input login/password in order for the MSI to start a command line and schedule several tasks during the installation process.

The IT guy is required to use a UPN or Down-Level Logon Name of a windows account which is granted built-in administrator privileges.

Since the application is meant to go global, I was wondering how could I fit in an UPN like ユーザー (japanese windows logon name 'User') in my command line :

```
SchTasks /Create /XML "task1.xml" /tn "Task 1" /RU "ユーザー" /RP password /F
```

The example above use japanese character set but it could be any non-latin character set,

Any help or advice appreciated on how to proceed,

Comment: Why is this a problem? Command-line parameters are Unicode in all modern versions of Windows. You don't have to do anything to make this work.

Comment: If I launched the command line in either Powershell or cmd.exe, task creation failed because no mapping could be established between account name and SID. Windows user has been properly created.